# Integrating Google + Facebook Authentication on ASP.NET Core WebAPI backend along React/Android app frontend

Tags: android, asp.net, reactjs, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

I've a

1. Webapp in **React.js**
2. An **Android** mobile app
3. An **ASP.NET Core WebAPI**

I want to integrate Google and Facebook authentication to my WebApp and Android app. User can choose either Google or FB to authenticate.

I was able to get access token from Google & Facebook with React app and Android app.
Now my question is

1. How can the WebAPI know where to validate the token? From Google or from Facebook?
2. I'm confused about the way this authentication federation works

What can be the step by step process on ASP.NET server to achieve the same? I was able to do react & android part but confused with C# part.

Or should I go for Identity Server 4 federation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Identity core and just let their Razor pages be you "login" screen. There's plenty of setup for this all over the internet. Identity core can then do the google/faceook buttons for you.

If you want to use the Identity core WebAPI and have the login form on the front end. Then you send the google id_token to your webAPI endpoint and you will use these modules for your login logic:

1. using Google.Apis.Auth; (google's nuget package)
2. var googleUser = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(request.Google_Id_Token) - Validate the google's Id token from the front end. Get the user's info from decoding the token.
3. userManager.FindByLoginAsync("google", googleUser.Email);  - Identity uses this to find social accounts.
4. userManager.AddLoginAsync()

There's not much information around on how to build this thing but those are your "pieces", give them a google and read the docs. I tried and failed, I thought I'd at least try and point you in the right direction!